# DROP USER CASCADE in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-drop

I had created a `USER`, named `Sandra` and I granted her a `SELECT` privilege to a `TABLE` with `GRANT OPTION`.

I had created another `USER`, named `Jim`.

`Sandra` then granted her `SELECT` privilege to `Jim`.

When I was trying to `DROP USER` Sandra, an error message came out saying:

```
Msg 15284, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The database principal has granted or denied permissions to objects in the database and cannot be dropped.
```

I'm wondering is there a `CASCADE OPTION` in `DROP USER`  in SQL Server 2005 databases?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no there is no such option. you have to wrote code for that to find and drop ownership owned by this user.

check the bwlow link.

[MSDN BOL "Drop User"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

**"Users that own securables cannot be dropped from the database. Before dropping a database user that owns securables, you must first drop or transfer ownership of those securables"**

Comment: _you must first drop or transfer ownership of those securables_ - **How this can be done?**

Comment: I believe you meant to ask, how can we do that in code/script? right? yes it is neither efficient nor easy to wrote such code more generically because how would you deiced if specific ownership need to be dropped or just transfer? this is cases by case user deiced by looking at an ownership only. for example if the user is owner of DB or has owner ship of one or more schema in DB. bottom line either do it case by case manually or come up with case specific custom scripts depending on your need.

Comment: In my case the user is grantor and he granted permission on object to other user. And I do not know how to revoke this permission or transfer it in order to drop the user. Pleas look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251144/cannot-revoke-permission-granted-by-other-user

Comment: I see your context now. i have posted the answer to your post as it is not 100% appropriate to this post.